# Cannot not choose the element in IE if there is an image at the background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Sorry for it's me again to ask the same question because I didn't make clear the question so that no one can help me to clarify my confusion yesterday. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpbOXJ)(seems it can't open in ie8).I want to drag the 'move-obj' but it doesn't work in IE browser(8,9,10) if there is an images at the background.How can I make this demo work on IE browser above IE8?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .wrap{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        padding: 10%;
    }
    .wrap-inside{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        width: 502px;
        height: 502px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .move-obj{
        cursor: move;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);//if I add the background, it will work correctly in IE9 IE10
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startcolorstr=#00000000,endcolorstr=#00000000); //doesn't work in IE8

    }
    .bg{
        top: 102px;
        left: 102px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <img class="bg" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">//if this tag remove, it work correctly
    <div class="wrap-inside">
        <div class="move-obj"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.move-obj').on('mousedown',function(e){
      var start_x = e.pageX;
      var start_y = e.pageY;
      var $that = $(this);
      var t_left = parseInt($that.css('left'));
      var t_top = parseInt($that.css('top'));
      $('.wrap-inside').on('mousemove',function(e){
        $that.css({
          left: t_left + e.pageX - start_x,
          top: t_top + e.pageY - start_y
        });
      }).on('mouseup',function(e){
        $(this).off('mousemove');
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: apply `higher z-index` to the element try this...it is working ok what do you expect?

Comment: It still doesn't work @guradio

Comment: Don't make duplicate questions, if you _"didn't make clear the question"_ in your original post, then edit the original post to be more clear.

Comment: Oh, i know it, thanks @Patrick Evans, but it seems when there is an answer to my question, people won't look into it though it doesn't solve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the a transparent image for a background of `.move-obj` or instead a transparent image try set it as `url(about:blank)` should also work.